# Get associated records for an array of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get associated records for an array of objects?

Associations:

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :posts
```

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

Below will return an array of posts of the first user

```
User.first.posts
```

How can I get the associated records for an array of user?

Is iterating through the array is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the posts that belong to specified users like this:

```
# users: ActiveRecord relation containing some of users
posts = Post.where(user_id: users.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: this is 2 queries :) `Post.where(user_id: users)` is 1 and would still work

Comment: You can use `joins`.